# On the page http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/mnist.html# the weight matrix dimension is incorrect

Tags: mxnet

Under Multilayer Perceptron subsection, the documentation says that weight matrix has a dimension of m*k.However, I think it should be k*m because the output layer-Y has the dimension of n*k.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

The correct matrix calculation formula for a `FullyConnected` layer is:

`output = input x weight_transpose + bias`

So in this formula, your input is `n x m`, your weight is `k x m` before being transposed, and your output is `n x k`. See the FullyConnected API doc [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.FullyConnected).

If you're just getting started, it may make sense to focus on the new [Gluon API](http://gluon.mxnet.io/), which is far easier to learn and debug.